# Count who paid group by 1, 2 or 3+

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a payment table like the example below and I need a query that gives me how many IDs paid (AMOUNT > 0) 1 time, 2 times, 3 or more times. Example:

```
+----+--------+
| ID | AMOUNT |
+----+--------+
|  1 |     50 |
|  1 |      0 |
|  2 |     10 |
|  2 |     20 |
|  2 |     15 |
|  2 |     10 |
|  3 |     80 |
+----+--------+
```

I expect the result:

```
+-----------+------------+-------------+
| 1 payment | 2 payments | 3+ payments |
+-----------+------------+-------------+
|         2 |          0 |           1 |
+-----------+------------+-------------+
```

ID 1: Paid 1 time (50). The other payment is 0, so I did not count. So, 1 person paid 1 time.

ID 2: Paid 3 times (10,20,15). So, 1 person paid 3 or more time.

ID 3: Paid 1 time (80). So, 2 persons paid 1 time.

I'm doing manually on excel right now but I'm pretty sure there is a more practical solution. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you explain your result

Comment: How 1 payment got value 2?

Comment: Give the Expected result based on above data

Comment: ID 1: Payd 1 time (50). The other payment is 0, so I did not count. So, 1 person payd 1 time. 
ID 2: Payd 3 times (10,20,15). So, 1 person payd 3 or more time.
ID 3: Payd 1 time (80). So, 2 persons payd 1 time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little sub-query will do the trick

```
Declare @YOurTable table (ID int, AMOUNT int)
Insert into @YourTable values
( 1 ,     50 ),
(  1 ,      0) ,
(  2 ,     10) ,
(  2 ,     20) ,
(  2 ,     15) ,
(  2 ,     10) ,
(  3 ,     80) 


Select [1_Payment] = sum(case when Cnt=1 then 1 else 0 end)
      ,[2_Payment] = sum(case when Cnt=2 then 1 else 0 end)
      ,[3_Payment] = sum(case when Cnt>2 then 1 else 0 end)
 From (
        Select id
              ,Cnt=count(*) 
         From  @YourTable 
         Where Amount<>0 
         Group By ID
      ) A
```

Returns

```
1_Payment   2_Payment   3_Payment
2           0           1
```

Answer (score 3):

To get the output you want try using a table to form the data and then SELECT from that:

```
with c as (
    select count(*) count from mytable where amount > 0 group by id)
select 
sum(case count when 1 then 1 else 0 end) "1 Payment"
, sum(case count when 2 then 1 else 0 end) "2 Payments"
, sum(case when count > 2 then 1 else 0 end) "3 Payments" 
from c
```

[Here is an example](http://rextester.com/ECNSQ8675) you can play with to see how the query is working.

Comment: Ok, my mis understanding then

Comment: @SandipPatel Because one of its payment is 0. Payment 0 doesn't count.

Comment: actually i consider 1 as id not no of payment